# ¿Cómo hago para programar sobre el menú de apagado del celular android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando crear una app pero para ello necesito saber cómo puedo programar sobre el menú de apagado, o en cuyo caso con el botón de apagado del celular android.

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es controlar el botón de apagado (detectar si se ha pulsado)? ¿Podrías incluir el código que lleves hasta el momento?

Comment: lo que se quiere hacer es crear un submenu que aparezca antes de que se muestre el menu de opciones de apagado al momento de pulsar el boton de power.

Comment: quiza si  agregas una imagen del resultado deseado pueda quedar mas claro para todos

Answer (score 2):

El menú de apagado que sale al pulsarse el botón de 'power' forma parte de la implementación de Android que tengas instalada. Para poder modificarla tendrías que ser root y modificar la imagen del sistema operativo que tiene el teléfono. En cualquier caso no es una tarea para una aplicación de Android.

Resumiendo: Por motivos de seguridad evidentes una aplicación convencional de Android no puede hacer nada con ese menú.